# Exception: multipart/form-data request failed in Spring Boot

Tags: spring

tech stack: Java 14, Spring Boot 2.5.3, MySQL 8.0.26, JPA

I'v got a spring boot uploading Excel web application. Excel file with 14KB capacity was uploaded successfully. However, if you try to upload an Excel file with 15MB and 50MB capacity, the following exception occurs.

I guess that server connection timed out when uploading. I guess the server to be closed before file is uploaded due to the short server connection time. To solve this problem, I tried to change the server settings in `application.properties`. I found some property. But it was not proper. The IDE underlines like this. I also visited [Spring Common Application Properties Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server) to find the appropriate property, but I couldn't find it.

I would like to know what causes the exception. And I wonder if this is the right way to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance. If you reply, I will reply as soon as possible.

**exception console**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.EOFException] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:805) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:42) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1172) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:640) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:317) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:600) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:975) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:879) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:106) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2922) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2824) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ...
```

**application.properties**

`server.tomcat.connection-timeout` is right. But `server.tomcat.disable-upload-timeout` and `server.connectionUploadTimeout` are not proper.

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=5000
server.tomcat.disable-upload-timeout=false
server.connectionUploadTimeout=5000

# MultiPart
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

**controller**

```
package com.nc.ojtfirstproject.web;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.nc.ojtfirstproject.message.ResponseMessage;
import com.nc.ojtfirstproject.service.StandardProductService;

@Controller
public class StandardProductController {
    
    private final StandardProductService standardProductService;

    public StandardProductController(StandardProductService standardProductService) {
        this.standardProductService = standardProductService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/excel/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        String TYPE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        String message = "";
        if (TYPE.equals(file.getContentType())) {
            try {
                standardProductService.save(file);

                status = HttpStatus.OK;
                message = "success: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                status = HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED;
                message = "fail: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
            }
        } else {
            status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            message = "Please upload excel file";
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
}
```

**service**

```
package com.nc.ojtfirstproject.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.nc.ojtfirstproject.domain.standardProduct.StandardProduct;
import com.nc.ojtfirstproject.domain.standardProduct.StandardProductRepository;

@Service
public class StandardProductService {

    private final StandardProductRepository standardProductRepository;

    public StandardProductService(StandardProductRepository standardProductRepository) {
        this.standardProductRepository = standardProductRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(MultipartFile file) {

        final int TRANSACTION_CHUNK_LIMIT = 10000;
        List<StandardProduct> standardProductList = new ArrayList<StandardProduct>();

        try {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            
            for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                StandardProduct standardProduct = new StandardProduct();
                
                standardProduct.setCode((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProduct.setCategoryCode((int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProduct.setName(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                standardProduct.setLowestPrice((int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProduct.setMobileLowestPrice((int) row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProduct.setAveragePrice((int) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProduct.setCompanies((int) row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());
                standardProductList.add(standardProduct);
                
                // TRANSACTION_CHUNK_LIMIT saveAll()
                if (TRANSACTION_CHUNK_LIMIT == standardProductList.size()) {
                    standardProductRepository.saveAll(standardProductList);
                    standardProductList.clear();
                    System.out.println(TRANSACTION_CHUNK_LIMIT + " success");
                }
            }
            
            workbook.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("save fail: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // TRANSACTION_CHUNK_LIMIT saveAll()
        try {
            standardProductRepository.saveAll(standardProductList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("save fail: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.nc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error and updated the following configuration parameters in the `application.properties` file like so:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=XX MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=XX MB
server.tomcat.connectionUploadTimeout=XXX (in miliseconds)
server.tomcat.connectionTimeout=XXX (in miliseconds)
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=XXX (in miliseconds)
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=XX MB
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=XX MB

server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=XXX (in miliseconds)
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout=XXX (in miliseconds)

server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=XXX MB
```

Setting these parameters like shown should solve the problem.